# Problema al cargar tablas relacionadas en base de datos

Tags: php, mysql, base-de-datos

Código

```
public function crear(array $data)
    {
    $db = (new Conexion())->getConexion();
    $query = "INSERT INTO productos (usuario_id, categorias_id, nombre, descripcion, precio, imagen, imagen_descripcion)
        VALUES (:usuario_id, :categorias_id, :nombre, :descripcion, :precio, :imagen, :imagen_descripcion)";
    $stmt = $db-> prepare($query);
    $stmt->execute([
        'usuario_id' => $data['usuario_id'],
        'categorias_id' => $data['categorias_id'],
        'nombre' => $data['nombre'],
        'descripcion' => $data['descripcion'],
        'precio' => $data['precio'],
        'imagen' => $data['imagen'],
        'imagen_descripcion' => $data['imagen_descripcion'],
        
    ]);
```

> Warning: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\Programacion\TP2-entrega\sitio\classes\Modelos\Producto.php
> on line 108 PDOException Object (
> [message:protected] => SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key
> constraint fails (`dw3_brandi_lucio`.`productos`, CONSTRAINT
> `fk_productos_categorias1` FOREIGN KEY (`categorias_id`) REFERENCES
> `categorias` (`categorias_id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO
> ACTION)
> [string:Exception:private] =>
> [code:protected] => 23000
> [file:protected] => C:\xampp\htdocs\Programacion\TP2-entrega\sitio\classes\Modelos\Producto.php
> [line:protected] => 108
> [trace:Exception:private] => Array

Comment: Ese tipo de errores ocurre cuando intentas insertar un registro huérfano, revisa bien el mensaje de error: *`Cannot add or update a child row`*  y te dice que el problema es con respecto a la tabla `categorias`. Es muy probable que el valor `$data['categorias_id']` no exista en la tabla `categorias`.